# How to convert P2PKH to Hash160 (or something else acceptable by Script)?

Tags: script, ruby

How to convert a bitcoin address (starts with `1`) to the right format acceptable by `script` (I'm using [this](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby) Ruby library)? I'm doing this:

```
tx.output do |o|
  o.value(50000)
  o.script { |s| s.recipient('1GzqkR2zNQUzHLpE7PLPjVNJ51FHC3bpDH') }
end
```

I'm getting:

```
RuntimeError: Script type must be hash160, pubkey, p2wpkh or multisig
```

I suspect there is something wrong with the format of the destination address. I [cross-posted](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby/issues/287) to GitHub too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a P2PKH address to a script, you first have to decode it using [base58check](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding).

Here is an example:

```
$ bs58 -dc 1GzqkR2zNQUzHLpE7PLPjVNJ51FHC3bpDH
00af7a4a30243f2301e6a14a4979ae099d52f560d4
```

Remove the prefix `00`, see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes. You are then left with the `hash160` of the pubkey, but this is not a full script. The P2PKH script looks like: `OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubKeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG`. So you need to add the missing ops:

- `OP_DUP = 0x76`
- `OP_HASH160 = 0xa9`
- `OP_EQUALVERIFY = 0x88`
- `OP_CHECKSIG = 0xac`

Resulting script: `76a9af7a4a30243f2301e6a14a4979ae099d52f560d488ac`

Note wallet software does all this for you when creating transactions based on an address.

#### Links

- [Bitcoin Wiki | Script](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script)
- [Bitcoin Wiki | Transaction (P2PKH)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Pay-to-PubkeyHash)
- Python Tools (bs58):
  https://github.com/jbaczuk/blockchain-dev-tools/